# Big Commerce 401 No credentials were supplied in the request

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a problem with connecting via the API.

The username and API key is correct and was working fine for the last few days

I created a new API KEY but no change.

I am able to login via the web browser via the URL
with the username and KEY in the popup, but i can no longer connect via the API

im looking for ANY pointers, as im willing to try anything.
I am using the legacy API and JSON responsesthe

Comment: can some explain the reason for the -1 down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`No credentials were supplied in the request` would indicate that your auth header didn't contain the api key or username. If you are using something like postman, you should see from the Authorization tab that Basic Auth has been selected and from the header tab, that you have an authorization header. If you are passing a request with another tool or in another fashion, check for an authorization header and ensure it is passing to the API along with your request.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am using postman as you described but i still get the 401 unauthorised error.    i have tried both the Base64 of the KEY and without, the username is also correct.

Comment: All fixed now, turns out the KEY was updated again by someone. thanks for the help @Alyss

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you could use [this client](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php) and just pass a couple parameters to establish a basic auth connection.

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => 'https://store.mybigcommerce.com',
'username'  => 'admin',
'api_key'   => 'd81aada4xc34xx3e18f0xxxx7f36ca'
));
```

- store url- https://{{your store hash here}}.mybigcommerce.com
- username - Create via legacy API accounts Settings
- api key - Create via legacy API accounts Settings

**Make sure you set up your app at https://developer.bigcommerce.com**